# Strange behavior of ZXing.Net when reading a barcode

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing.net

My code:

```
        IBarcodeReaderGeneric reader = new BarcodeReaderGeneric()
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            TryInverted = true,
            Options =
            {
                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.CODE_39 },
                TryHarder = true,
                ReturnCodabarStartEnd = true,
                PureBarcode = false
            }
        };
```

Getting a barcode:

```
    using (var img = RotateImage(newBitmap, -90, true, true, Color.White))
    {
        lum = new BitmapLuminanceSource(img);
        barcode = reader.Decode(lum)?.ToString(); 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcode))
        {
            return img;
        }
    }
```

The method that rotates the image:

```
     public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image inputImage, float angleDegrees, bool upsizeOk,
                                     bool clipOk, Color backgroundColor)
    {
        // Test for zero rotation and return a clone of the input image
        if (angleDegrees == 0f)
            return (Bitmap)inputImage.Clone();

        // Set up old and new image dimensions, assuming upsizing not wanted and clipping OK
        int oldWidth = inputImage.Width;
        int oldHeight = inputImage.Height;
        int newWidth = oldWidth;
        int newHeight = oldHeight;
        float scaleFactor = 1f;

        // If upsizing wanted or clipping not OK calculate the size of the resulting bitmap
        if (upsizeOk || !clipOk)
        {
            double angleRadians = angleDegrees * Math.PI / 180d;

            double cos = Math.Abs(Math.Cos(angleRadians));
            double sin = Math.Abs(Math.Sin(angleRadians));
            newWidth = (int)Math.Round(oldWidth * cos + oldHeight * sin);
            newHeight = (int)Math.Round(oldWidth * sin + oldHeight * cos);
        }

        // If upsizing not wanted and clipping not OK need a scaling factor
        if (!upsizeOk && !clipOk)
        {
            scaleFactor = Math.Min((float)oldWidth / newWidth, (float)oldHeight / newHeight);
            newWidth = oldWidth;
            newHeight = oldHeight;
        }

        // Create the new bitmap object. If background color is transparent it must be 32-bit, 
        //  otherwise 24-bit is good enough.
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, backgroundColor == Color.Transparent ?
                                         PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb : PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        newBitmap.SetResolution(inputImage.HorizontalResolution, inputImage.VerticalResolution);

        // Create the Graphics object that does the work
        using (Graphics graphicsObject = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
        {
            graphicsObject.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphicsObject.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphicsObject.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            // Fill in the specified background color if necessary
            if (backgroundColor != Color.Transparent)
                graphicsObject.Clear(backgroundColor);

            // Set up the built-in transformation matrix to do the rotation and maybe scaling
            graphicsObject.TranslateTransform(newWidth / 2f, newHeight / 2f);

            if (scaleFactor != 1f)
                graphicsObject.ScaleTransform(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

            graphicsObject.RotateTransform(angleDegrees);
            graphicsObject.TranslateTransform(-oldWidth / 2f, -oldHeight / 2f);

            // Draw the result 
            graphicsObject.DrawImage(inputImage, 0, 0);
        }
```

I'm trying to read a barcode from a scanned image that is rotated 90 degrees. I use the standard code to rotate the image, the code is read from this image:

[image]

note which large spaces on the top and bottom, you can get them if you call the method in the following way: **RotateImage(newBitmap, -90, false, false, Color.White)**

But if the image is rotated as positively, as in the picture:

[image]

then the bar code can not be read! Why is this happening? After all, the second image is correctly rotated, unlike the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I want to advise you to work with Spire.Barcode, it is also free of charge and does a much better job of its task. With her, I had no problems.